# How to resample using custom frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I know the Pandas `.resample()` method can down sample using a regular interval. What if I have irregular intervals? This code doesn't work. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if a function already exists.

```
d = {'ticker': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
 'date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],  
 'return': [.01, .011, .012, .013, .014, -.02, -.01, .01, .02, -.03]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
dates = ['2021-01-03', '2021-01-05']
```

[image]

```
df.resample(dates).sum()
# ValueError: Invalid frequency
```

What I want.

| ticker | date | return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-03 | 0.033 |
| A | 2021-01-05 | 0.027 |
| B | 2021-01-03 | -0.02 |
| B | 2021-01-05 | -0.01 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
>>> mask = df.date.where(df['date'].isin(dates)).bfill()
>>> df.groupby([df.ticker, mask]).sum().reset_index()

  ticker        date  return
0      A  2021-01-03   0.033
1      A  2021-01-05   0.027
2      B  2021-01-03  -0.020
3      B  2021-01-05  -0.010
```

Comment: Very clean! Nice.